# Domain for main document root gets pointed to newly enabled subdomain document root

Tags: apache, dns, ubuntu-16.04, virtualhost, webmin

I have a Ubuntu 16.04 which apache2 server is running. I have a website hosted in my primary domain which the document root is **/var/www/html**.

I use Webmin to create a subdomain and I have given the document root as **/var/www/mysite**.

when I restart the server and visit the main domain, it shows the website that I hosted in the **/var/www/mysite**, which is the subdomain document root.

If I remove or rename the conf file under **/etc/apache2/sites-available/{created-subdomain.conf}** file, the main domain again shows the website hosted in the  **/var/www/html** document root.

What are the possible causes for this. I want my main domain to show the website I hosted in **/var/www/html** and subdomain to show the website I placed in **/var/www/mysite**

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not setting up `ServerName domain.com` in your configs, so Apache simply chooses the first one (alphabetically by Config file name) to serve.

Comment: I have added the ServerName into the config files in the sites-available folder. Another interesting finding is that even though i rename the config files' extension to an unusable format, still the main website gets displayed.

Comment: hmm... are you sure you're restarting web server?

Comment: Yes I am. service apache2 restart. Not sure if there is any other configuration that runs by default